# Displaying Telstra Vector Tile Server data in QGIS 3.14.16-Pi

Tags: qgis, visualisation, vector-tiles, pbf

I am running QGIS 3.14.16-Pi and am wanting to load the layers Telstra (Australian telephone company) provides on their GIS server.
https://staging.gcm.telstra.com.au/gisserver/rest/services/Hosted/

I have tried the Vector tiles plugin without success.
I am unsure of the syntax of the URL to enter into the Vector tiles plugin.
i have tried these below, as well as removing various levels of the URL:

[https://staging.gcm.telstra.com.au/gisserver/rest/services/Hosted/CATM_D_External_antenna/{z}/{x}/{y}.pbf](https://staging.gcm.telstra.com.au/gisserver/rest/services/Hosted/CATM_D_External_antenna/%7Bz%7D/%7Bx%7D/%7By%7D.pbf)
https://staging.gcm.telstra.com.au/gisserver/rest/services/Hosted/CATM_D_External_antenna/VectorTileServer?f=jsapi

The data displays well on a browser when clicking through the ArcGIS JavaScript link
https://staging.gcm.telstra.com.au/gisserver/rest/services/Hosted/IoT_CatM1/VectorTileServer

I am sure if it will load it is a simple format issue or use of another plugin.

Answer (score 3):

Choose a layer, copy the URL and add `/tile/{z}/{y}/{x}.pbf` to it.

Then in the QGIS Browser -> Vector Tiles add that URL as a new connection

You can discover the tile URL by clicking on the layer then clicking the little JSON link at the top and looking at the `tiles` element.

In the example below I use "[Hosted/Mobile_All_Outdoor](https://staging.gcm.telstra.com.au/gisserver/rest/services/Hosted/Mobile_All_Outdoor/VectorTileServer) (VectorTileServer)" layer.

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: I just asked a similar question and while this loads, when you zoom in the data disappears. Is there a workaround for this? https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/394274/loading-pbf-vector-tile-data-in-qgis/394278?noredirect=1#comment645767_394278