# Loading PBF vector tile data in QGIS

Tags: qgis, import, vector-tiles, pbf

Is it possible to load the services in https://staging.gcm.telstra.com.au/gisserver/rest/services/Hosted into QGIS.

I have tried a Virtual Layer, Vector Tile and ArcGIS Map/Feature service with no luck.

In https://crowdsupport.telstra.com.au/t5/network-roaming/gis-layer-of-telstra-mobile-coverage/td-p/893241 a poster mentions that QGIS 3.14 can't load the format (PBF) but is it possible in newer versions and if so how?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, just add it as a Vector Tile Server.

In a web browser, go to https://staging.gcm.telstra.com.au/gisserver/rest/services/Hosted, select your layer, eg. Mobile_All_Outdoor, right click and copy the URL:

https://staging.gcm.telstra.com.au/gisserver/rest/services/Hosted/Mobile_All_Outdoor/VectorTileServer

Go to QGIS (I'm using 3.18), open the Browser panel, right click "Vector Tiles" and select "New ArcGIS Vector Tile Service Connection..."

- Name: Mobile_All_Outdoor
- Service URL: https://staging.gcm.telstra.com.au/gisserver/rest/services/Hosted/Mobile_All_Outdoor/VectorTileServer
- Max Zoom Level: 19

[image]

```
<!DOCTYPE connections>
<qgsVectorTileConnections version="1.0">
    <vectortile zmin="0" referer="" name="Mobile_All_Outdoor" serviceType="0" authcfg="" password="" username="" styleUrl="" url="https://staging.gcm.telstra.com.au/gisserver/rest/services/Hosted/Mobile_All_Outdoor/VectorTileServer" zmax="19"/>
</qgsVectorTileConnections>
```

Comment: When I do this I get an error `Invalid Data Source: serviceType=arcgis&type=xyz&url=https://staging.gcm.telstra.com.au/gisserver/rest/services/Hosted/Mobile_All_Outdoor/VectorTileServer&zmax=19&zmin=0 is not a valid or recognized data source.' . When I use @eurojam's answer I can't zoom in. Can you save and send me the xml of the connection.

Comment: Unfortunately it doesn't load. I was using 3.16 and am just updating but can you send the xml from the save tab when you go to Vector Tiles?

Comment: It works in 3.18. It would have helped if you'd specified your version in your qestion.

Comment: Works in 3.16 for me, Vector Tiles works nicely. Vector Tiles in the browser is different than XYZ tiles http://url/VectorTileServers/tile/{z}/{y}/{x}.pbf. This doesn't work  
https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/374819/displaying-telstra-vector-tile-server-data-in-qgis-3-14-16-pi

Answer (score 4):

Yes, it is possible, using vector tiles and use the URL like this one (tested with QGIS 3.16):

[https://staging.gcm.telstra.com.au/gisserver/rest/services/Hosted/Wholesale_4G_3G_High_Contrast/VectorTileServer/tile/{z}/{x}/{y}.pbf](https://staging.gcm.telstra.com.au/gisserver/rest/services/Hosted/Wholesale_4G_3G_High_Contrast/VectorTileServer/tile/%7Bz%7D/%7Bx%7D/%7By%7D.pbf)

[image]

Comment: This loads but doesn't seem to be correctly projected. For example when I add a basemap WMS feed the data doesn't show. Is there a way to change/check projections on the telstra vector tile as properties shows no CRS etc? The info is there when you go to the page directly in a browser. https://gisservices.information.qld.gov.au/arcgis/rest/services/Basemaps/QldBase_Colour/MapServer/WMTS/1.0.0/WMTSCapabilities.xml

Comment: from the metadata it should be 3857. on my map it lies in australia and fits to OSM more or less..

Comment: Did you try to zoom in - it disappears when I try and doesn't match with the QLD WMS feed I linked above. When I go to it's properties it doesn't show any projection info but in the page it does have 3857 - https://staging.gcm.telstra.com.au/gisserver/rest/services/Hosted/Mobile_4G_ExtAntenna/VectorTileServer

Comment: yes it is strange...I remarked this with the disappearing...sorry but no further ideas on that